# What is a comparable asset manager for Code Igniter to Carabiner?

Tags: php, codeigniter, asset-management

Carabiner seems like a solid asset manager for CodeIgniter but it isn't maintained. Is there a comparable asset management plugin that's well maintained for Code Igniter? As a side question, is there a template management plugin you recommend and why?

Comment: This may be better suited to the Code Igniter forums, they have a very active community from what I recall.

Comment: I don't know of any alternatives but I researched the options and went with Carabiner for the last two projects I've worked on.

It's not maintained as such but a lot of people are using it and I'm sure the Codeigniter community will quickly fix any problems that arise.

Answer (score 0):

I use asset from Sparks at http://getsparks.org/packages/assets/versions/HEAD/show and seems to work great.

Comment: This link is now outdated/broken. Perhaps update with a newer solution or delete the answer?